# How to mask credit card number except the last four digits using Regex

Tags: regex, perl, credit-card

I'm trying to solve a problem where I input the name of the person, his credit card number. It must identify which company the card is from and also mask the digits of the number except the last four. For example the following lines

```
'Preston: 345678901234567'
'601234123456737 is a Discover card'
```

*Would change to*

```
'Preston: ....4567'
'....6737 is a Discover card'
```

So far I've done how to validate the inputs to the card companies using the http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html:

```
American Express: ^3[47][0-9]{13}$ 
Discover: ^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$
MasterCard: ^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}$
Visa: ^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$
```

I'm confused as to how to mask rest of the digits except the last four digits and there aren't many articles and resources for assistance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215714/discussion-on-question-by-ash-k123-how-to-mask-credit-card-number-except-the-las).

Answer (score -1):

Following code demonstrates how CC number can be masked on all digits but last four.

- Obtain data from a user (name,number)
- In a loop check number against regular expression for each card
- If number matches regular expression
- Mask all digits but last four
- print message
- leave loop

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %re_cc = (
        'American Express'  => qr/^3[47][0-9]{13}$/,
        'Discover'          => qr/^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$/,
        'MasterCard'        => qr/^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}$/,
        'Visa'              => qr/^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/
);

while( my $record = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $record;
    my( $name, $number ) = split ' ', $record;
    while( my ($cc_name,$cc_regex) = each %re_cc ) {
        if( $number =~ /$cc_regex/ ) {
            $number =~ s/(\d+)(?=\d{4})/'*' x length($1)/e;
            say "$name\t$number\n$number is a $cc_name";
            last;
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
Preston     345678901234567
```

Output

```
Preston ***********4567
***********4567 is a American Express
```